# Which answer to accept?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637807/why-is-homm-n-not-necessarily-a-module) and got three very similar answers almost at the same time. I have got the answer to my question and found the answers helpful so I upvoted them all. But now I am confused as to which one should I accept as all are similar ? What are the community guidelines in such cases ? Thanks !

Comment: Decide arbitrarily or go to random.org to decide, upvote the winner and post a comment under the other two answers that you equally like the other two answers.

Comment: Here is a similar older post: [What factors should be considered to accept an answer: Time, completeness or what?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/what-factors-should-be-considered-to-accept-an-answer-time-completeness-or-wha). You can find some other related questions in the *linked questions* there.

Comment: @Phira You mean "accept the winner", right?

Comment: I gave several solutions to this age old problem, see my comment [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11985/only-one-answer-allowed-which-one-to-accept#comment46714_11985).

Comment: @DanielR Yes, I do.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a personal take:

I think you should always accept the best answer, but as you say, they are all the same (pretty much)

I would never accept an answer posted MUCH later than already existing answers, if they say pretty much the same stuff.

Then, consider accepting the answer from the guy with lowest reputation. This is like positive discrimination. I believe this would be a good thing for community. It encourage people who have just started participating to make further contributions.

And to be fair to the others for their time, give them an upvote each.

Comment: +1 for the part from the guy with lowest reputation (assume all the answers are nearly all the same and posted at around same time)

Comment: +1 for the lowest reputation thing.

Comment: Agreed with the above two. With all of the posts I see about new users being frustrated about not being able to get rep, it's nice to take a stance that shows that we appreciate the little guy's contribution too.

Comment: @achillehui Agreed. Sadly, not all people think this way: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511009/problem-15-from-hersteins-book